# Visual Studio 2010 - Using editor FileNameEditor in Project Settings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a bunch of paths to use in my project. When you use Appication Settings you can provide the Settings object to a `PropertyGrid` with the code: `PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = My.Settings()`.

I read that you can provide an object (in this case a custom object, not `My.Settings` with this *meta* information:

```
<Editor(GetType(System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor), _
        GetType(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))>
```

in order to apply an editor that opens up a file browser, when you use `PropertyGrid`. Thats great and works.

Is there any possibilities of doing such thing within the VS2010 UI to be used with Application Settings?

I mean, I realized that setting the type of a property to `System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor` will sets its type and not its editor, thats trivial. I've also tried to set `System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor` as a provider of that property without luck.

I've opened the file `Settings.Designer.vb`, I've manually added the line:

```
<Editor(GetType(System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor), _
        GetType(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))>
```

to the property I want to show a file picker and works. The problem is that the file is auto-generated and should not be edited.

How can I procede in order to repeat that behaviour using the appropiate procedure with Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Just read the application settings into your own class and assign that class to the propertygrid.  I took this edited somewhat from one of my projects:

```
Call MyFilenameClass
 <Editor(GetType(System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor), GetType(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor)), _
  Browsable(True), _
  DefaultValue(""), _
  Category("File"), DisplayName("Filename"), Description("Select the file.")> _
  Public Property MyFileName As String = My.Settings.MyFilename
End Class
```

So, when the class is created, MyFilename will have the value of My.Settings.MyFilename. In your Form_Closing you will need to put your value back into the Application setting and save it:

```
My.Settings.MyFilename = "class name in here".MyFilename
My.Settings.Save
```

Comment: This is the straighforward solution of what I'm stating about editing an auto-generated file. I was hoping to find a Tool and/or option in the VS2010 for the job, as the editor I'm trying to use is a default editor provided in the .Net framework. In that way, I would keep the settings autogenerated with the correct editor. In other words, I felt like there wasn't the need to provide custom code por default editors (just pointing which editor to use and VS2010 would add the appropiate meta for the property). +1 for your answer anyway.